# Secrets are not available in Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, docker-swarm

I create secret "databasePassword" using the below command:

`echo 123456 | docker secret create databasePassword -`

Below is my yml file to create the MySQL and phpMyAdmin where I'm trying to use this secret in the yml file.

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: db-mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'false'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: /run/secrets/databasePassword
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
    secrets:
      - databasePassword

  beyond-phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: beyond-phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db-mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8081:80
```

But the databasePassword is not getting set as 123456. It is set as the string "**/run/secrets/databasePassword**" I tried using `docker stack deploy` also, but it also didn't work.

I tried setting the secrets at the end of the file like below by some web research, but it also didn't work.

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: db-mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'false'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: /run/secrets/databasePassword
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
    secrets:
      - databasePassword

  beyond-phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: beyond-phpmyadmin
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db-mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8081:80
secrets:
  databasePassword:
    external: true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker cannot know that `/run/secrets/databasePassword` is not a literal value of the `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` variable, but a path to a file that you would like to read the secret from. That's not how secrets work. They are simply available in a `/run/secrets/<secret-name>` file **inside the container**. To use a secret, your container needs to read it from the file.

Fortunatelly for you, the `mysql` image knows how to do it. Simply use `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE` instead of `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`:

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'false'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/databasePassword
    secrets:
      - databasePassword

...

secrets:
  databasePassword:
    external: true
```

See "Docker Secrets" in the mysql image [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql).